# KafkaUtils.createStream stops capturing data after a while

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have built a Kafka consumer that fetches from Kafka writes to Elasticsearch, the program runs as expected for a day or two, and then spark stops capturing data. Kafka logs are being generated and the spark stream is running but no data is captured. Below is the code being used:

```
# For Spark
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

# For Kafka
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

# Name of Spark App
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("test_topic")

# Spark and Spark streaming configuration
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

# Kafka Enpoints
zkQuorum = '192.0.23.1:2181'
topic = 'test_topic'


# Elastic Search write endpoint
es_write_conf = {
    "es.nodes" : "192.000.0.1",
    "es.port" : "9200",
    "es.resource" : "test_index/test_type",
    "es.input.json": "true",
    "es.nodes.ingest.only": "true"
}


# Create a kafka Stream
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "cyd-pcs-bro-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})

# Print stream to console
kafkaStream_json = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: x[1])
kafkaStream_json.pprint()

#Write Stream to ElasticSearch
kafkaStream.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
    path='-',
    outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat",
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",
    conf=es_write_conf)
)


# Start the stream and keep it running unless terminated
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

1. Is there something else that my code should be doing or a way to dig deeper into the issue(logs dont indicate anything)?
2. Also, if I am okay to have one Spark App per topic, is there any other reason that I would want to use `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream`. Since I don't want to have the overhead of managing offsets.

Language used: *Pyspark*

Code run:

```
sudo $SPARK_HOME/spark-submit --master local[2] --jars /home/user/jars/elasticsearch-hadoop-6.3.2.jar,/home/user/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.3.1.jar /home/user/code/test_stream.py
```

This is the output of the stream when no data is being captured:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2018-08-29 12:23:46
-------------------------------------------

18/08/29 12:23:46 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1535525626000 ms.0 from job set of time 1535525626000 ms
18/08/29 12:23:46 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.030 s for time 1535525626000 ms (execution: 0.007 s)
18/08/29 12:23:46 INFO PythonRDD: Removing RDD 115 from persistence list
18/08/29 12:23:46 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 115
18/08/29 12:23:46 INFO BlockRDD: Removing RDD 114 from persistence list
18/08/29 12:23:46 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 114
18/08/29 12:23:46 INFO KafkaInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[114] at createStream at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0 of time 1535525626000 ms
18/08/29 12:23:46 INFO ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches: 1535525624000 ms
18/08/29 12:23:46 INFO InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata: 1535525624000 ms
18/08/29 12:23:47 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1535525627000 ms
18/08/29 12:23:47 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1535525627000 ms.0 from job set of time 1535525627000 ms
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2018-08-29 12:23:47
-------------------------------------------

18/08/29 12:23:47 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1535525627000 ms.0 from job set of time 1535525627000 ms
18/08/29 12:23:47 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.025 s for time 1535525627000 ms (execution: 0.005 s)
18/08/29 12:23:47 INFO PythonRDD: Removing RDD 117 from persistence list
18/08/29 12:23:47 INFO BlockRDD: Removing RDD 116 from persistence list
18/08/29 12:23:47 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 117
18/08/29 12:23:47 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 116
18/08/29 12:23:47 INFO KafkaInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[116] at createStream at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0 of time 1535525627000 ms
18/08/29 12:23:47 INFO ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches: 1535525625000 ms
18/08/29 12:23:47 INFO InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata: 1535525625000 ms
18/08/29 12:23:48 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1535525628000 ms
18/08/29 12:23:48 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1535525628000 ms.0 from job set of time 1535525628000 ms
```